# Normalising a 2D histogram

Tags: python, c++, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a 2D histogram h1 with var1 on the x axis and var2 on the y axis, which I've plotted from a `dataframe`. I have normalised it as I want in c++ but now need to do the same in python and am struggling with how to get and set bin content.

The idea is to remove the effect of having more events in one part of the distribution than in another and only leave the correlation between `var1` and `var2`.

Working Code in c++:

```
double norm = h1->GetEntries()/h1->GetNbinsX();
 
    int nbins = h1->GetNbinsX();
    for(int i = 1; i< nbins+1; i++)
      {
        double nevents = 0.;
        for(int iy = 1; iy< h1->GetNbinsY()+1; iy++)
          {
          float bincont = h1->GetBinContent(i,iy);
          nevents+=bincont;
          }

        for(int iy = 1; iy< h1->GetNbinsY()+1; iy++) 
        {
          float bincont = h1->GetBinContent(i,iy);
          float fact = norm/nevents;
          float value = bincont*fact;
          h1->SetBinContent(i,iy,value);
        }
      }
```

Attempt for code in python:

```
plt.hist2d(var1, var2, bins=(11100, 1030), cmap=plt.cm.BuPu)

norm = 10
for i in var1:
    nevents = 0.
    for j in var2:
        plt.GetBinContent(i,j)
        nevents+=bincont

    for j in var2:
        plt.GetBinContent(i,j)
        fact = norm/nevents
        value = bincont*fact

        plt.SetBinContent(i, j, value)
```

Edit after help from @JohanC:

Problem has been resolved. Make sure you don't have nan-s when normalising, because dealing with them is always a pain.

Comment: hey, welcome to stack overflow! I noticed you have `var21` in the python code, is that supposed to be `var1`?

Comment: Hi @Warlax56, you are right. Thank you! I edited. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To manipulate the contents of the bins, you could first calculate them, change them and only then draw the plot.

`plt.hist2d()` returns the bin contents (a 2D matrix) together with the bin edges in both directions. To get the same information without plotting, `np.histogram2d()` returns exactly the same values. Afterwards, the result can be plotted via `plt.pcolormesh()`.

For some reason, the returned matrix is transposed. So, the first step is to transpose it again.

To calculate sums and do multiplications and divisions on 2D arrays, numpy has some powerful array and [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) operations. The double loops in C++ are just one operation in numpy: `hist *= norm / hist.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)`. As the denominator can be zero, the warning can be suppressed (the result will be `NaN`s and `Inf`s that are ignored for plotting).

Here is some demo code.  Note that using `bins=(11100, 1030)` is extremely large. The code below uses much smaller values.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 1000000
var1 = np.concatenate([np.random.uniform(0, 20, size=9 * N // 10), np.random.normal(10, 1, size=N // 10)])
var2 = var1 * 0.1 + np.random.normal(size=N)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))

norm = 10
binsX = 200
binsY = 100
ax1.hist2d(var1, var2, bins=(binsX, binsY), cmap='BuPu')
ax1.set_title('regular 2d histogram')

hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(var1, var2, bins=(binsX, binsY))
hist = hist.T
with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):  # suppress division by zero warnings
    hist *= norm / hist.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)
ax2.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, hist, cmap='BuPu')
ax2.set_title('normalized columns')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: About `hist *= norm / hist.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)`:

- `hist.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)` creates a new matrix (name it `s`) where for each `h[i, j]` the elements are replaced by the sum over all `i`, so `s[i, j] = sum([h[k,j] for k in range(0, N)])`. Without `keepdims=True`, a 1D array would be created with only the sums.
- `hist *= norm / s` creates a loop over all `i,j` as in `h[i,j]=h[i,j]*norm/s[i,j]`.  Division by zero creates `NaN` when dividing zero by zero, and `inf` when dividing another number by zero.  These values are ignored by `pcolormesh`.

Optionally you could execute [`nan_to_num()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html):

```
hist = np.nan_to_num(hist, nan=0, posinf=0, neginf=0)
```

Comment: Hi @JohanC. Thank you very much for your solution. It works perfectly with your example for var1 and var2. For some reason though, when I input mine from my data file, it gives me the following error:

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  cbook._putmask(xa, xa < 0.0, -1)

and an empty normalised plot. Do you happen to know what could be the problem? I remove NANs and reset the index with:

df = df.dropna()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know how to post a pic here, so posted as a separate answer. I've tested the bins too , I will look at the rest now.

Comment: Ok, you were right, For some reason hist.sum(axis=1)  are all NAN even though all the rest is as expected. Error/Warning occurs right after the normalisation.

Comment: NaN's occur when dividing zero by zero. To see more colors, you can also try a lognorm for the colors: `ax2.pcolormesh(..., norm=matplot.colors.LogNorm())`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the region below 20 either. I just don't see where would those 0s come from. All my values as seen on the first plot are fine and I remove all the possible NANs before plotting . Perhaps I don't understand something about how the normalisation happens?